# I don’t know how to find the exact position of a word withing a query in a field in solr?

Tags: solr

My problem would be complex to solve, I had installed solr into my debian 9 virtual machine with the purpose of make insertion massive data test. Specifically through the script

> bin/post

Its uploaded all the pdf and doc files to my collection in solr. My question is at the time of making a query in the content my result is the whole content and not show me where are the result. I want to know through the query where are the word or sentences exactly.

For example:

```
"content":["This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test \n"], "metadata.X-Parsed-By":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser", "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"], "metadata.Content-Encoding":["ISO-8859-1"], "metadata.resourceName":["tika_extract.py"], "metadata.Content-Type":["text/x-python; charset=ISO-8859-1"], "id":"4ebba9d3-239c-494d-9a1f-9ec16610530b", "_version_":1630918290423414784},
```

query:

```
{content: "test"}
```

My current result is:

```
"content":["This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test\n This is my \nfirst test \n"]
```

And I need this result:

> "content": ["This is my \n**first** test\n This is my \n**first**
>   test\n This is my \n**first** test\n This is my \n**first** test\n
>   This is my \n**first** test \n "]

My main target is just know where are the match words into the content or the whole sentence, is not a problem other alternatives.

Wait my question be the best explained.

Comment: Seems like [highlighting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/highlighting.html) is what you want?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes bro this is. (y)